# Error when load Spark-nlp pretrainedPipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

One exception occurred when I load a spark nlp pretrainedPipeline as following:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59

I am new to Scala, can anyone recognize the reason? Thank you in advance.

My code:

[image]

My dependencies:

[[image]]2]

Exception details:

[image]

Comment: seems like you are using old Java version

Answer (score 0):

The code and build.sbt look well.
Keep in mind that you need to use Java 1.8.x in order for Spark-NLP to work.
Please check requirements here,

https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#requirements

And Scala steps here,

https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#scala

Alberto.